# How to execute a shell script from a TCL script

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, exec, eval

I have a Shell script that reads in another file as an argument. In Shell terminal, I use it like the following:

```
source checker.sh waiver.file
```

Now, I would like to source this shell script in a TCL script like following
**TCL_script.tcl**

```
link
set RUN .
exec checker.sh waiver.file
```

When I execute the above TCL script, the terminal is just hung and it doesn't work.

Can any experts here please help me in running a Shell script in a TCL script?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run the script manually via: `./checker.sh waiver.file`?

Comment: Make sure it has execute permissions. What. are `link` and `RUN` for?

Comment: Does `checker.sh` exist in your path?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, checker.sh does exist in the path.

Answer (score 4):

How to run that depends critically on how exactly that `checker.sh` works. The issue is that the shell's `source` command works by reading the script and executing it within the current shell session (Tcl's `source` works similarly, but it's for a different language). Because it is in the same session, it has all sorts of access to capabilities that it effectively would not as a subprocess (or rather it would have them, but they wouldn't persist).

The simple way to run that from Tcl is this (assuming you're in the right directory):

```
exec sh checker.sh waiver.file
```

*I would not be surprised if that has problems!* Unfortunately, the set of possible problems is so thoroughly wide that it's extremely hard to guess how to resolve them ahead of time.

That said, the fact that you're getting a hang *is* useful information. That probably means that the script is trying to access standard in and out in ways that are not particularly happy with a pipeline. We can try resolving that with redirections:

```
exec sh checker.sh waiver.file <@stdin >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

If that doesn't work, you might need to run things using Expect. The `expect` program is Tcl, but with some extra commands. This might be enough to get you started:

```
spawn sh
send "source checker.sh waiver.file\r"
interact
```

There's an awful lot more to using Expect well.

(It's possible that rewriting `checker.sh` might be easier; the details matter utterly here.)